# Kotlin - Collect All Items That Existed between a Particular Date Range Based on Creation Date?

Tags: kotlin

I am working on collecting items based on a particular input start and end time (as `Instant`).

These items look like the following:

```
data class Item (val created: Instant, val name: String)
```

When I am trying to do is get all of the items that exist between a particular start and end time. So as an example (just for simplicity assume seconds here):

```
Item1 - created: 2 seconds
Item2 - created: 5 seconds
Item3 - created: 9 seconds
Item4 - created: 12 seconds
```

Given an input of `getItem(from = 3 seconds, to = 13 seconds)` I should get all of the items returned, because although Item1 wasn't created after 3 seconds, it existed before Item2 was created.

Alternatively, if the input was `getItem(from = 5 seconds, to = 9 seconds)` I should only get items 2 and 3 because they were created and existed across the entire range.

What's the best way of doing this in Kotlin?

Getting items created between the input range is fairly trivial and would look something like (assuming the items were sorted):

```
items.filter {
    it.created.isAfter(start) && it.created.isBefore(end)
}
```

But this misses items that may have existed in the input, but were not created during the input.

Comment: Could you explain your requirement a bit more clearly please? In particular, I can't understand how you tell from your example that ‘Item1 … existed before Item2 was created’, nor why that should affect the results. And why doesn't similar apply to your second example? (Would it help to give timestamps in your example instead of durations?)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the previous value. Something like this should work:

```kotlin
fun Iterable<Item>.getActiveItems(start: Instant, end: Instant): List<Item> {
    require(end >= start)
    var prev: Item? = null
    val result = mutableListOf<Item>()
    for (item in this) {
        if (item.created <= start) prev = item else {
            prev?.let(result::add)
            prev = null
            result += item.takeIf { it.created <= end } ?: break
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- The list is ordered by `created`
- Items `created` exactly at `start` are included, but not any before
- Items `created` exactly at `end` are included, but not any after

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on indexing iteration, but the same general principle as @Ruckus T-Boom 's answer.

```
fun List<Item>.getItems(from: Instant, to: Instant): List<Item> {
    var startIndex: Int? = null
    var endIndex: Int? = null
    run loop@ {
        this.forEachIndexed { i, item ->
            if (startIndex == null) {
                when {
                    item.created > from -> startIndex = i - 1
                    item.created == from -> startIndex = i
                }   
            }
            if (endIndex == null) {
                when {
                    item.created > to -> endIndex = i - 1
                    item.created == to -> endIndex = i
                }
            }
            if (startIndex != null && endIndex != null) {
                return@loop
            }
        }
    }
    if (startIndex == null) {
        return emptyList()
    }
    if (endIndex == null) {
        endIndex = this.size - 1
    }
    return this.subList(startIndex!!, endIndex!! + 1)
}
```

This doesn't cover all the possible edge cases, but handles well the cases in your example as well as some others (you can check for yourself [here](https://pl.kotl.in/z9Z1fDn8S))